# How do I setup etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.cf for testing the sendmail command on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to send a test email through port 25 to service provider?

Tags: 22.04, sendmail

Installation:

```
$ sudo apt install sendmail 
Rhe following packages will be REMOVED
      postfix
```

Desktop: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (NOT server)

File: /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

Edited with:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

Contents:

```
root=john@G31T-M3
hostname=localhost
mailhub=mail.btinternet.com:25
AuthUser=johndoe71@btinternet.com
AuthPass=johndoe71
```

Post Installation check:

```
$ ps -e | grep sendmail
12358 ?        00:00:00 sendmail-mta
```

I am getting error:

```
sendmail: 553 <john@localhost> Invalid mail address, must be fully qualified domain
```

My local-host-names

```
localhost
```

I am running a simple desktop on Ubuntu and I know that I have to connect through port 25 to get through my broadband (changed to 465 when shared hosted), since the above configuration is very similar to my windows 10 home setup but I am unsure what to call my hostname since I am technically not a server just a localhost so I feel localhost is an appropriate name for the hostname. As a local host I have not setup a DNS.

I am developing on apache2 with php and phpMailer to be specific. Sendmail in its simplistic form is just one of three of the possible mailing options that I am developing for and I will later have to develop for SMTP. Before I consider moving to Ubuntu 22.04 Server.

I am testing with the following command:

```
echo "Subject: hello" | sendmail johndoe71@btinternet.com
```

Tried 127.0.0.1 and got the same error.

Any suggestions on the domain name will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok so I have managed to get it running and my sendmail checks are going out from the command line.  The default hostname, apparently is ubuntu.local which a substituted in place of hostname. I do not know whether this is ideal?